# Supported Audio file formats in iPhone

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

What are the supported audio files formats in iPhone?

If I want to play a 2 hour audio files , what is the best audio file format I should have in my App?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

mp3 why not.
**From:** [The Multimedia Support Section of the Reference Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html)

Audio Playback and Recording Formats

The audio playback formats supported in iOS are the following:

- AAC (AAC-LC)
- HE-AAC (v1 and v2)
- xHE-AAC - *supported since iOS 13.0*
- AC-3 (Dolby Digital) - *supported since iOS 9.3*
- E-AC-3 (Dolby Digital Plus) - *supported since iOS 9.3*
- MP3 (MPEG-1 audio layer 3
- <del>AMR (Adaptive Multi-Rate, a format for speech)</del> - *not supported since iOS 4.3*
- ALAC (Apple Lossless)
- iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, another format for speech)
- IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
- linear PCM (uncompressed)
- µ-law and a-law

The audio recording formats supported in iOS are the following:

- AAC (on supported devices only)
- ALAC (Apple Lossless)
- iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, for speech)
- IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
- linear PCM
- µ-law and a-law

Comment: Apple dropped support for AMR in iOS 4.3.  See @Ash's answer for the current list.

Comment: Great list!

Personally I would go with AAC, because it has a smaller file size and better sound quality compared to file size than mp3. Additionally it is not patented nor requires a license to be used, unlike mp3 ([AAC Licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding#Licensing_and_patents), [mp3 Licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing.2C_ownership_and_legislation)). 

AAC is supported by almost all modern platforms, including iOS (preferred format) and Android.

Answer (score 5):

iOS Supports these audio types...

@"aac",@"adts",@"ac3",@"aif",@"aiff",@"aifc",@"caf",@"mp3",@"mp4",@"m4a",@"snd",@"au",@"sd2",@"wav"

Comment: Try recording and MP3 and let me know. As clearly stated by @flycomputer no MP3 recording.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple iPhone supports the following audio formats:

- AAC (16 to 320 Kbps)
- AIFF
- AAC Protected (MP4 from iTunes Store)
- MP3 (16 to 320 Kbps)
- MP3 VBR
- Audible (formats 2-4)
- Apple Lossless
- WAV