# Wav File Header

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development. I need to write out the header of the WAV file format. I cannot write it properly.

Can you help?

Comment: If you are talking about WAV audio file, i think WAV is not supported on iPhone. see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761460/supported-audio-file-formats-in-iphone

Comment: I thought OpenAL could load WAV, even on iPhone?

Comment: @lukya, WAV file format is definitely supported on the iPhone. But maybe your thinking of iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

this page should give you all you need to know to create a valid WAV file:

http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html

Answer (score 0):

Also, [check out this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/):

But to be honest this question is too vast and general to be answered here. You should probably be reading up on how to do this [with the MIT Audio programming book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=12283) or the [newly published core audio book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/audio/9780321636973/understanding-core-audio/1?query=%28core+audio%29#snippet). Once you get started you could come back here for specific questions.