# what are the formats supported in AVAudioRecorder for recording sound?

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I have found a list of the different values (Audio Data Format) at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004488

Audio Data Format Identifiers
Identifiers for audio data formats, used in the AudioStreamBasicDescription structure.

kAudioFormatLinearPCM               = 'lpcm',

kAudioFormatAC3                     = 'ac-3',

kAudioFormat60958AC3                = 'cac3',

kAudioFormatAppleIMA4               = 'ima4',

kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC                = 'aac ',

kAudioFormatMPEG4CELP               = 'celp',

kAudioFormatMPEG4HVXC               = 'hvxc',

kAudioFormatMPEG4TwinVQ             = 'twvq',

kAudioFormatMACE3                   = 'MAC3',

kAudioFormatMACE6                   = 'MAC6',

kAudioFormatULaw                    = 'ulaw',

kAudioFormatALaw                    = 'alaw',

kAudioFormatQDesign                 = 'QDMC',

kAudioFormatQDesign2                = 'QDM2',

kAudioFormatQUALCOMM                = 'Qclp',

kAudioFormatMPEGLayer1              = '.mp1',

kAudioFormatMPEGLayer2              = '.mp2',

kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3              = '.mp3',

kAudioFormatTimeCode                = 'time',

kAudioFormatMIDIStream              = 'midi',

kAudioFormatParameterValueStream    = 'apvs',

kAudioFormatAppleLossless           = 'alac'

kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_HE             = 'aach',

kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_LD             = 'aacl',

kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_ELD            = 'aace',

kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_HE_V2          = 'aacp',

kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_Spatial        = 'aacs',

kAudioFormatAMR                     = 'samr',

kAudioFormatAudible                 = 'AUDB',

kAudioFormatiLBC                    = 'ilbc',

kAudioFormatDVIIntelIMA             = 0x6D730011,

kAudioFormatMicrosoftGSM            = 0x6D730031,

kAudioFormatAES3                    = 'aes3'

However, I dont think we can use all the formats mentioned  (e.g. mp3).

Can anyone help me out with the formats that are supported for recording sound using AVAudioRecorder ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per apple docs [Apple Core Audio Format Specification 1.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAFSpec/CAF_spec/CAF_spec.html) it should now support mp3 although I haven't tested it, this is the current enumeration they support:

```
enum {
    kAudioFormatLinearPCM      = 'lpcm',
    kAudioFormatAppleIMA4      = 'ima4',
    kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC       = 'aac ',
    kAudioFormatMACE3          = 'MAC3',
    kAudioFormatMACE6          = 'MAC6',
    kAudioFormatULaw           = 'ulaw',
    kAudioFormatALaw           = 'alaw',
    kAudioFormatMPEGLayer1     = '.mp1',
    kAudioFormatMPEGLayer2     = '.mp2',
    kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3     = '.mp3',
    kAudioFormatAppleLossless  = 'alac'
};
```

Comment: thanks.any idea how to easily convert to mp3 from any of the above ?

Comment: Is this still up to date? What is the source of this list?

Comment: @StephenGroom It seems like it should support mp3 now, I have updated my answer with the most up to date format/codec support

Comment: Is it possible to save recorded file in .3gp format.

Comment: What file extension does... "alaw" use, for example?

Answer (score 4):

List above just

> currently defined values for the mFormatID field

not supported for recording.

There are tested with AVAudioRecorder formats (with sample rates):

```
"MPEG4AAC (8000, 11025, 22050, 32000, 44100, 48000)",
"AppleLossless (8000, 11025, 22050, 32000, 44100, 48000)",
"MPEG4AAC_HE (32000, 44100, 48000)",
"MPEG4AAC_LD (22050, 32000, 44100, 48000)",
"MPEG4AAC_ELD (22050, 32000, 44100, 48000)",
"MPEG4AAC_ELD_SBR (22050, 32000, 44100, 48000)",
"MPEG4AAC_ELD_V2 (22050, 32000, 44100, 48000)"
```

Example:

```
[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL
                            settings:@{
                                       AVFormatIDKey : @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                                       AVSampleRateKey : @(44100.0),
                                       AVNumberOfChannelsKey : @(2)
                                       }
                               error:&error];
```

also
[Supported Audio file formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761586/6528403)

Comment: Could you please let me know which one produces the best recording?

Comment: The best quality? AppleLossless 48000,  I guess. I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. I found that and ima4 same and best quality. Thanks :)