# How to record audio as mp3 file by using AvAudiorecorder in iOS

Tags: iphone, record, avaudiorecorder

How to record audio as an mp3 file by using AvAudiorecorder?
I am using the following code for the recorder setting

```
recordSetting =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                   AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                   [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                   AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                   AVSampleRateKey, nil];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to record an audio file in .mp3 format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871940/how-to-record-an-audio-file-in-mp3-format)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3] forKey:AVFormatIDKey
```

However it's impossible to encode mp3 format at IPhone because of royalty.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback i used this but i m getting error 
"Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1718449215 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.)"
.please provide me complete setting code,if possible,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Whilst you can play MP3 files using `AVAudioPlayer`, you can't record in MP3 format with `AVAudioRecorder` (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867994/what-are-the-formats-supported-in-avaudiorecorder-for-recording-sound) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871940/how-to-record-an-audio-file-in-mp3-format)). If you need a compressed format, but it doesn't have to be MP3, I suggest recording in AAC format.