# How to record sound in mp3 format in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mp3, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

I want to record the sound in my iPhone app,but i can only record it in some specific formats.How to record in mp3 format
I have searched lot,but could not find a solution

I found AVRecorder wont support mp3 recording,even though there are many apps in itunes which record in mp3 format

How can I achieve this,Please help me..thanks in advance

Comment: First Try searching Internet :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314510/how-to-record-audio-as-mp3-file-by-using-avaudiorecorder, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549023/iphone-app-recording-audio-in-mp3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871940/how-to-record-an-audio-file-in-mp3-format, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005598/looking-for-a-way-to-encode-mp3-on-iphone

Comment: The recorded file is in .caf file format. You have to convert .caf to.mp3 file format after recording.

Comment: @iAmbitious How to convert .caf to .mp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) is the solution of your question.

This demo is developed by apple and usefull for audio recording in mp3 format. I have already developed one app([BRL App](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/battleraplive/id346512771?mt=8)) using this demo.

This is very very helpfull demo developed by apple developers.

Comment: Trouble with post links is they can sometimes be removed :'( but google doesn't know that

Answer (score -1):

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@\"mp3Header\" ofType:@\"mp3\"];

NSMutableData *audioData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

int samples = 22050;

uint8_t dataToRecord[samples];

int x;

for(x = 0; x < samples; x++) {

```
// populate the \"dataToRecord\" array with audio data. //
```

}

[audioData appendBytes:(const void *)dataToRecord length:samples];

```
// Get path to documents folder and set a file name  //
```

[audioData writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES];