# Can I play mpga auido in ios?

Tags: ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play one media stream by MPMoviePlayer, it can play h264 video but there is no sound output. I want to know is there any framework can handle the mpga audio ?

I can play it by VLC and got the media information as follow:

[image]

Comment: what's the problem?  is MPMoviePlayer playing the whole movie (audio and video) and you're just trying to get the audio track out of that?

Comment: There is no sound when play movie :(

Comment: do you want only the audio or do you want both audio & video?

Comment: I want to play audio and video, now the player can only play video, no audio output :(

Answer (score 1):

[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW20) states that MPMoviePlayerController can play any audio file that iOS supports natively.

But unfortunately for you, ["`mpga`" format is not one of the audio file formats supported natively in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761460/supported-audio-file-formats-in-iphone).

You're going to have to find a way to convert the "`mpga`" track to something iOS can use.

Answer (score 0):

MPGAs files are basically mp3 but AvPlayer can't play them due to its file extension . 
you can change file extention to mp3 easily and then player will work and can play the file.

Comment: i surprised when i faced this situation.if extensions matter then what is UTI concept in this situation.