# iOS Deprecated Audio Format - AMR (Adaptive-Multi-Rate)

Tags: ios, api, audio, deprecated, amr

So this is something I've been trying to get my head around when I was trying to load one of my older apps.

There's a lot of threads where people are asking for the supported audio formats in iOS. And in most of them someone comments that support for AMR (Adaptive-Multi-Rate) was dropped in iOS 4.3. How do they know this?
[Supported Audio file formats in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761460/supported-audio-file-formats-in-iphone)

But I cannot find ANY api changes or anything about this in Apples official documentations.

i.e the diffs between 4.2 and 4.3:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS43APIDiffs/

**How can I get som actual documents saying that this actually happened?**

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I ever found to a document or official statement were [two](https://devforums.apple.com/message/405994#405994) [responses](https://devforums.apple.com/message/405269#405269) (login required) by an Apple Employee on the old [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com), both saying:

> As of 4.3 iOS does not support encoding or decoding AMR.
>   If you want AMR you'll have to put in your own decoder.

Comment: But it's kind of weird that this is not in any official documentation.

Comment: It is weird - and now the old devforums don't seem to be available any more. Too bad!