# Swift 2 - m4a file won't play on iOS

Tags: ios, swift2, avaudioplayer, m4a

I'm trying to play an m4a file on an iOS device programatically. The file is downloaded from a server and stored. When the user presses a button, it is played. The file, when copied from the device to OSX does play fine. I am using the code

```
var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playAudio(sender: UIButton!) {
    let audioPath = FileUtils.getPath(audioPaths[sender.tag])
    print("PATH " + audioPath)//The printed path IS DEFINETLY correct
    do{
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath))
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    }
}
```

The path is correct so I'm not sure why it won't work. Could it be the format (even though it plays on OSX)?

An example file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/csewwg6n9vzan5z/131015-08%3A13%3A30.m4a?dl=0

Comment: How audioPaths are initialized?

Comment: It's fairly complex buy I can assure you the path is valid

Comment: BTW, the `do { }` block is unnecessary if you're using `try!`

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? ("try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error…")

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes I get an error. Not at Mac right now but I'll post the error tomorrow. Its nothing meaningful just says that it failed and the app crashes

Comment: can you provide a link to the file in question?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Will do in when I have access to the Mac

Comment: @RhythmicFistman the console output, when catching the error and printing it, is the following: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"

Comment: @RhythmicFistman this is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/csewwg6n9vzan5z/131015-08%3A13%3A30.m4a?dl=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That file won't play on iOS because it's encoded in AMR NarrowBand, [which is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32832948/22147).

I would try re-encoding the m4a files as AAC, or switch to mp3.

Comment: Im going to accept this answer because it's the one which helped both, but @matt you were helpful too, I can only choose one though

Answer (score 1):

It's likely just a feature of the way this `m4a` file is compressed. The simple fact is that not every `m4a` file, even if it is a perfectly valid file, will play on your device. (For example, perhaps this file is *very* compressed.) And to make things more complicated, it differs from device to device! And to make things even *more* complicated, the file might play in the Music app but not in an AVAudioPlayer!!

To test this theory, recode the file as a more middle-of-the-road `m4a` and see if *that* plays.

Comment: Makes sense but is there no workaround? The fact that osx can play the file proves its possible

Comment: I don't think you're listening to what I'm saying. The fact that OS X can play the file _is the problem_. This is a file that OS X can play _but your iOS device cannot_. Trust me. I've had it happen to me.

Comment: @HamzahMalik Are you starting to believe me now?

Comment: What I'm getting at is: the file is a valid m4a but not supported. How can I make it supported? (Libraries, different encoding etc)