# Swift: AVAudioPCMBuffer vs AVAudioBuffer vs AVAudioCompressedBuffer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiopcmbuffer

I'm currently using an AVAudioPCMBuffer to play a .wav file in a simple game. However, when checking the documentation for it, I came across two other types of buffers I never saw anywhere else, the ones in the title: AVAudioBuffer and AVAudioCompressedBuffer.

Which buffer should I be using, and why? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can someone respond please :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AVAudioBuffer` is the superclass of `AVAudioPCMBuffer` and `AVAudioCompressedBuffer`.

You shouldn't have to deal with `AVAudioBuffer` it in practice, normally you just use its subclasses.

- `AVAudioPCMBuffer` is to be used for playing uncompressed, PCM encoded data (such as what a .wav file contains)
- `AVAudioCompressedBuffer` supports different compressed formats (see [Supported Audio file formats in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761460/supported-audio-file-formats-in-iphone))

For your specific use case, I'd suggest using a simpler way to play the file: `AVAudioFile(forReading: URL)` which you can directly feed into a `AVAudioPlayerNode` using `scheduleFile(_:, at:)` which would automatically handle the buffering.