# Which audio formats (extensions) work on ios and Android with the just_audio Flutter package?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

**Which audio formats (extensions) work on ios and Android with the just_audio Flutter package?** Wondering which extensions I should allow users to upload with file_picker such that they play with the just_audio package (I couldn't find a list anywhere). To clarify the files will be stored on Firebase therefore played via url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On iOS, the AV Foundation Framework is used, and the supported formats are listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761460/supported-audio-file-formats-in-iphone).

On Android, ExoPlayer is used, and the supported formats are listed in the [ExoPlayer documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/supported-formats.html).