# What are supported file formats for just_audio 0.9.29 Flutter Package

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am doing a project and planning to use **just_audio 0.9.29** Flutter package, but I could not find list of supported file formats in documentation. Where can I find this information?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think the question is clear, but Mohit, did you search for existing answers before posting a new question? All just_audio questions are tagged with just-audio to make them easy to search.

Comment: I thought I saw a comment of yours earlier that you flagged it as a duplicate, but I can't see it flagged so I'll try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which audio formats (extensions) work on ios and Android with the just\_audio Flutter package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557707/which-audio-formats-extensions-work-on-ios-and-android-with-the-just-audio-flu)