# TYPE_SOURCE: None of the available extractors (just_audio flutter)

Tags: exoplayer, just-audio

Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (PsExtractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.

i had try to play [ac3, aif, mpeg, au, aiff, aifc, caf, sd2] (https://cdn.playmiapp.ca/dev/albums/1667207325524_ac3.ac3
https://cdn.playmiapp.ca/dev/albums/1667207328383_aif.aif) these format in just-audio flutter but i'm not able to play these format files in just_audio flutter android. These format files are worked in iOS but in android coming the following error :-

Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (PsExtractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557707/which-audio-formats-extensions-work-on-ios-and-android-with-the-just-audio-flu/73559391#73559391

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.. switch to assetsAudioPlayer. works perfectly with downloaded files when using path_provider

Comment: Provide references if any